# Oracle 11 query group/count and split result by hour

Tags: oracle, group-by, count, distinct

I have a simple query on Oracle v11 to group and count records, nothing special:

```
select ADDR, count(ADDR) from DBTB group by ADDR;
```

The rable have also the TIMESTAMP column, what I'm trying to do is group and count unique ADDR by hour.
e.g. on table:

```
TIMESTAMP               ADDR
19-OCT-2021 17:15:00    12345
19-OCT-2021 17:20:00    12345
19-OCT-2021 17:25:00    12345
19-OCT-2021 17:27:00    67890
19-OCT-2021 18:10:00    55555
19-OCT-2021 18:20:00    55555
19-OCT-2021 18:30:00    66666
19-OCT-2021 18:43:00    77777
```

The output should be:

```
HOUR  COUNT
17        2
18        3
```

Could someone help me to do a query to count and group the same ADDR split by hour?
Thank you
Lucas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TO_CHAR()` to get the hour of each timestamp:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR("TIMESTAMP", 'HH24') HOUR,
       COUNT(DISTINCT "ADDR") COUNT
FROM DBTB
GROUP BY TO_CHAR("TIMESTAMP", 'HH24');
```

Probably you also need to group by the date:

```
SELECT TRUNC("TIMESTAMP") DAY,
       TO_CHAR("TIMESTAMP", 'HH24') HOUR,
       COUNT(DISTINCT "ADDR") COUNT
FROM DBTB
GROUP BY TRUNC("TIMESTAMP"), TO_CHAR("TIMESTAMP", 'HH24');
```

Or filter for a specific date:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR("TIMESTAMP", 'HH24') HOUR,
       COUNT(DISTINCT "ADDR") COUNT
FROM DBTB
WHERE TRUNC("TIMESTAMP") = TO_DATE('19-Oct-2021', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
GROUP BY TO_CHAR("TIMESTAMP", 'HH24');
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0c62056b04218682cfa1ae4ef82b453a).

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why I got:
GROUP BY EXTRACT(HOUR FROM "TIMESTAMP")
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-30076: invalid extract field for extract source

Comment: @LucasRey I don't know why you get this error. As you can see in the demo all queries are syntactically correct and return the expected result.

Comment: maybe I have to use to_char for timestamp

Comment: @LucasRey what is the data type of timestamp?

Comment: It's DATE. But if I just select it I got 03-OCT-21 with TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMP, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') I can see also the hour, minute, second, etc

Comment: @LucasRey I assumed that a column named timestamp would be a TIMESTAMP. See my edited answer.

Comment: Yep! Solved using to_char(TIMESTAMP,'HH24')  thank you very much